# How to check prime number with an input set as LIMIT

Tags: php, forms, html-table, primes

So i have the code to check for Prime numbers with value that is inputted.  My question is, how can i turn my code so that the table can be dynamic in sets of 10 and the max is 100?  So that the input can only take increments of 10 and the max value you can enter 100?

My current code right now is set to 10 columns and 4 rows so is there a way to make this change (dynamic i guess?) to change with the input increments of 10?

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <table border="2" width="1180px">
        <thead>
            <center>
                Number Chart</center>

        </thead>

    <?php
    error_reporting(0);

    function isPrime($n)
    {
    if ($n == 1) return false;
    if ($n == 2) return true; 
    if ($n % 2 == 0)
        {
        return false;
        }

    $i = 2;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++)
        {
        if ($n % $i == 0)
            {
            return false;
            }
        }

    return true;
    }


    if (isset($_POST['value']) && $_POST['value'] != 0)
    {
    /* @var $start type */
    $start = $_POST['value'];
    }
    else
    {
    $start = 1;
    }


    $n_cols = 10;
    $n_rows = 5;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n_rows; $i++) // 
    {
    $col = '';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $n_cols; $j++)
        {
        $number = ($start - $i - ($j * $n_cols));

        if (isPrime($number) == true)
            {
            //if prime color it red
            $col.= '<th style="color:red">' . ($start - $j - ($i * $n_cols)) . 
    '</th>';
            }
          else
            {
            $col.= '<th>' . ($start - $j - ($i * $n_cols)) . '</th>';
            }
        }

    $out.= '<tr>' . $col . $row . '</tr>';
    }

    echo $out;
    ?>

     <tr>   
            <thead colspan=10>
                    <center>
                        <label for="input">Enter Limit:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="value" style="width: 60px">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                    </center>
            </thead>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: for a start turn error reporting back on

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: i would change input to a select and give the option of 10,20...100 that should solve it if i understand correctly

Comment: @rtfm So as a radio button? The assignment is to enter a value into the input box but if you do not enter anything other than an increment of 10 to give an error saying "you must enter a valid value"

Comment: no a select `<select name='value><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option> etc </select>`

Comment: @rtfm ok this almost works for my assignment, but the it requires for the user to type in the value... and if the value is not an increment of 10 or over 100, for the input box to give you an error saying "You must enter a valid value".  For instance, if i typed 15 the input box would read out "You must enter a valid value"   Thanks in advance man.  I usually never get responses here.

Comment: @rtfm This is a good start.... so now, the input box is displaying the error, but the chart still shows up reading the primer numbers for the next 50 values.  So for instance, if i type 15 and submit, the error "you must enter a valid value" shows up, but the chart still displays a table starting from 15 to the next values of prime numbers... How do i get the chart not to display if the user entered an incorrect value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (($_POST['value'] % 10) != 0 || $_POST['value'] >100 ){ 

echo 'you must enter a valid value';

}else{
  //all the code you want to run only if the number posted is valid
}
```

the % is Modulo, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php for more details

Comment: Dude this is awesome it worked..... NOW... the last thing i need is that can the table change to the input?  So the columns will always be 10.  But can it change the rows depending on the input?  For instance, if its 10, it only has one row because it has 10 columns.  If i type 20, then 2 rows, 30, 3 rows, and so on....

Comment: basic maths 10/10=1, 20/10=2 etc

Comment: so how would i write that so that the rows are dependent on the input the user puts?  would i use the % where i define the rows?

Comment: i really dont see how you cant do this based on what you have done so far.

Comment: thanks man i figured it out... should i edit my post with all the correct coding and mark this as solved?